# Function returns linked list - C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to C programming and I have the following problem in my program. I create a polynomial as a linked list in a function (POLYmake) and I want to return this list in main function in the variable poly1 (and poly2 for the second polynomial). What should be the syntax for the return statement?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct node
{
int sunt;
int dun;
struct node* next;
} Poly;


Poly POLYmake();

int main()
{
Poly poly1, poly2;

printf("Doste to 1o poluwnumo : \n");
poly1 = POLYmake();

printf("Doste to 2o poluwnumo : \n");
poly2 = POLYmake();

}

Poly POLYmake()
{
Poly *head;
Poly *curr;
head = NULL;

int stop = 1;
int i = 1;
int suntelestis, dunami;
char x;
while(stop != 0)
{
    curr = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));
    int y=1;
    printf("Doste to suntelesti tou %dou orou : ",i);
    scanf("%d",&suntelestis);
    curr->sunt = suntelestis;

    printf("Doste ti dunami tou %dou orou : ",i);
    scanf("%d",&dunami);
    curr->dun = dunami;

    curr->next = head;
    head = curr;

    printf("Yparxei kai allos oros tou polywnumou? (Y or N) : ");
    scanf("%s",&x);

    while(y == 1)
    {
        if(x == 'Y')
        {
            y=0;
            i++;                
        }
        else if (x == 'N')
        {
            stop=0;
            y=0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Yparxei kai allos oros tou polywnumou? (Y or N) : ");   
            scanf("%s",&x);
        }
    }
}
return ????????? ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Poly *POLYMake()
{

...
    return head;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: When I return head I get this message "[Error] incompatible types when returning type 'struct Poly *' but 'Poly' was expected". If I declare POLYMake as a pointer function then Poly variables poly1 and poly2 must be declared as pointers. But according to my excercise, poly1 and poly2 must be Poly variables.

Comment: How is the problem worded?

Comment: I have to create two polynomials in a function and then I have to add them in another function: Poly POLYadd(Poly p, Poly q) . So this function has Poly parameters which actually are the two polynomials I created in the POLYMake function.

Comment: Does Poly have to be a struct node? Could it be a struct node*?

Comment: According to the excercise the second function has to be declared like that "Poly POLYadd(Poly p, Poly q) ", not "Poly * POLYadd(Poly p, Poly q)". So I think that Poly has to be a struct node, not a struct node* .

Comment: If you `typedef struct node * Poly` then `POLYadd()` can return a `Poly`, not a `Poly*`. It will also make life easier when you come to call `free()`.

Comment: I tried this and I get the following messages: [Error] request for member 'sunt' in something not a structure or union, [Error] request for member 'dun' in something not a structure or union, [Error] request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union
Can you explain me what should I change because this is my first program and I am quite confused?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94463/discussion-between-darwin-von-corax-and-konstantina-papagiannopoulou).